# Unsupported feature error in Quickbook

Tags: java, quickbooks

I am trying to executing following code

```
DataService service = new DataService(context);
com.intuit.ipp.data.Class a = new com.intuit.ipp.data.Class();
a.setName(accountClassName);
return service.add(a);
```

and I am getting following error with a message.

ERROR DETAIL:Feature Not Supported Error : We're sorry. This feature is not included in your QuickBooks Online subscription.

I have bought a subscription from quickbook online but I don't know which other service package to buy to support this feauture. I am able to create Customer and Account entries but I am unable to create Journal entries.

Comment: @Lakshman I am using Java v3 SDK for QBO libraries for accessing quickbook online version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class Tracking facility should be added in order to create journal entry. It will facilitate tracking of financial transactions between two accounts and make sure that both accounts can be in sync.